# Add an image after link using CSS don't work in firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I want to add an icon (a small triangle) under a link using the CSS :after attribute, It works in Chrome but not in Firefox and IE. Here is the result in chrome:

[image]

but in IE and firefox here is the result:

[image]

The CSS code:

```
li.ui-state-active > a:after {
width: 22px;
height: 19px;
position: absolute;
display:block !important;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -11px;
bottom: -19px;
z-index: 2;
content: '';
**background-image: url(#{resource['img:css/arrow-menu-onglet.png']}) no-repeat !important;**
}
```

also I tried this but with the same result (ok in just chrome):

```
li.ui-state-active > a:after {
width: 22px;
height: 19px;
position: absolute;
display:block !important;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -11px;
bottom: -19px;
z-index: 2;
**content: url(#{resource['img:css/arrow-menu-onglet.png']}) no-repeat !important;**
}
```

Can you help me please figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

No image needed:

```css
/* tabbed nav */

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav li a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
nav li a.state-active:after,
nav li a.state-active:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0;
}
nav li a.state-active:after {
  bottom: -15px;
  border-top: 15px solid #fff;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
}
nav li a.state-active:before {
  bottom: -23px;
  border-top: 23px solid #DBD5C7;
  border-left: 23px solid transparent;
  border-right: 23px solid transparent;
}
/* ----- */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 20px;
  background: #DBD5C7;
}
div {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" class="state-active">LINK 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">LINK 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">LINK 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div></div>
```